# WordPress - IF statement not working within archive.php

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax

I'm looking to add a simple IF statement to check whether a custom field is selected, and if so, add the code 'display:none'.

I have the code I want to add:

```
if( get_field('my_custom_field') )
{
    echo "";
}
else
{
    echo "style='display:none'";
}
```

But, if I add this code where I want it, it throws an error, plus, becaus eof where it's being placed, no matter what other php type code I add, it throws up an error, I believe it's because it's in some kind of loop  it's not allowing it, hopefully you'll be able to assist, here is the code it's sitting within:

```
$offices.= '

<div class="office_section" id="office_part_'.$locator.'">
    <h1>'.$officetitle.'</h1>
    '.$room_specs.'

    <div class="office_dimensions_holder"  *** this is where I would like to 
add custom IF statement, but doesn't allow me to ***>       

        <div class="dimensions">
        <div class="dimension_sml">Dimensions: </div>
            '.$dimension1.'
```

I imagine it's because it's within the $offices.= '  call, so would appreciate the correct syntax to allow me to check the custom field I have recently added is true and if not...then add a display:none.

Comment: Syntax errors in my code editor. The thing is the page, loops through the posts for 'offices' and prints out all the results....some posts I don't want to have a certain section IF a custom field is checked.... So this is what I'm trying to achieve,

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this question about php syntax...
Correct one should looks like:

```
$offices.= '
    <div class="office_section" id="office_part_'.$locator.'">
    <h1>'.$officetitle.'</h1>
    '.$room_specs.'
    <div class="office_dimensions_holder" '.(get_field('my_custom_field') ? "" : "style='display:none'").'>       

        <div class="dimensions">
        <div class="dimension_sml">Dimensions: </div>
            '.$dimension1.'
```

Comment: Hi Vladimir - So I added this code, it parsed ok, but doesn't have the desired outcome, , do I still need to add the 'if/else parts?'

Comment: hi @user2736203. If/else already there. You see: `(get_field('my_custom_field') ? "" : "style='display:none'")`. So - if you do not see "style='display:none'" it means that get_field('my_custom_field') returned true... Or do you have other logic to show/hide this element?

Comment: I've gone through some posts, some I've checked, some I havn't...but in the loop, all the results are coming back as 'FALSE' - so they all say 'display:none' - Which is strange because at least some should be TRUE.

I'm using this from advanced custom fields for wordpress > http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/true-false/

Comment: Perhaps you are using get_field() method not inside post. Then you have to set post ID to get_field('field_name', POST_ID_HERE). See description of this method: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Comment: I'm using it inside archive.php > Currently the loop works and pulls all the data/custom fields, it's just this new option I've added, doesn't seem to apply. I'll take a look at what you suggested now and report back.

Comment: How can I assign a post ID, when the page is looping through all posts within the 'office' post type?

Comment: No, I just can't get it to work, looking at the code as a whole, the way the loop for $offices is being called, do you think that's why it's not applying the display:none for each individual office and instead just applies it across every instance? Instead of applying it where it should be e.g. whether it's True or False.

Comment: man, I do not know your code to decide what to do better. You asked what was wrong with part of your code and you have answer. Now it is work for your brains :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up entering this outside my code and then called the  conditional inside it:

```
$showdimensions = get_field('show_dimensions');

if(!empty($showdimensions)){
    $showdimensions = 'style="display:none"';
} else {
    $showdimensions = '';
}
```

Then within the original code added:

```
'.$showdimensions.'
```

to pull in the display:none if the checkbox was not checked.